# Modifying 3 dimensional array in function in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, 3d

I have a 3D array declared in main() function:
`char currentPositions[5][6][2];`
And i want to modify this array using another function:
`SetDefaultPositions(currentPositions);`
This function looks something like this:

```
void setDefaultPositions(char positions[5][6][2]){
    char defaultPositions[5][6][2] = {
        {"()", "()", "..", "..", "..", ".."},
        {"/\\", "/\\", "/\\", "/\\", "/\\", "/\\"},
        {"..", "..", "..", "..", "..", ".."},
        {"/\\", "/\\", "/\\", "/\\", "/\\", "/\\"},
        {"..", "..", "..", "..", "..", ".."}
    };
    positions = defaultPositions;
}
```

I tried using pointers but it keeps telling me things like this:
expected 'char (**)[2]' but argument is of type 'char (*)[6][2]'
warning: passing argument 1 of 'setDefaultPositions' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
Or no errors, but printing currentPositions showed that it was empty.
I understand nothing, I also tried some solutions from web but I can't find someone with similar problem.
It's school project and I am not allowed to use global variables.

Comment: Aside: do you realise they are not C strings – there is no nul terminator?

Comment: `"()"` is _not_ a single character. So, it can _not_ be stuffed into a `char`. And, to use a character constant, you'd need `'()'` (single quotes). But, this is _two_ chars. So, again, not possible. You could (can only) do: `'('` or equiv.

Comment: The `positions = defaultPositions;` will have no effect for the caller. The array passed is in effect a pointer, so you are just overwriting the argument, not the array. And you can't copy an array with `=` anyway. *I tried using pointers* – please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem.

Comment: @CraigEstey this works perfectly fine if I assign it to my variable in main

Comment: As mentioned, you are not assigning it to the array in `main()` that was passed. The passed array decays to a pointer, and what you are doing is to overwrite the pointer argument passed.

Comment: I think you want: `char defaultPositions[5][6][2] = { { {'(', ')'}, ...  }, { ... }, { ... }, { ... }, { ... } };` That is: `"()"` --> `{ '(', ')' }` And, for the assignment: `positions = defaultPositions;` --> `memcpy(positions,defaultPositions,5 * 6 * 2);`

Comment: @WeatherVane

#include <stdio.h>

void setDefaultPositions(char *(positions)){
    positions[0] = 'a';
    positions[1] = 'b';
}

int main()
{
    char currentPositions[2];
    setDefaultPositions(currentPositions);
    printf("%c, %c", currentPositions[0], currentPositions[1]);
    return 0;
}
Somethinh like this works perfectly fine on 1dimensional array, but i cannot figure out how to change a 3d array assigning a new one

Comment: Please edit the post to include formatted code!

Comment: @WeatherVane
Okay, so how can i make this work?

Comment: @WeatherVane Arrgh! Fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass an array to a C function. It decays to a pointer.
You can do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void setDefaultPositions(size_t size, char positions[5][6][2]){
    char defaultPositions[5][6][2] = {
        {"()", "()", "..", "..", "..", ".."},
        {"/\\", "/\\", "/\\", "/\\", "/\\", "/\\"},
        {"..", "..", "..", "..", "..", ".."},
        {"/\\", "/\\", "/\\", "/\\", "/\\", "/\\"},
        {"..", "..", "..", "..", "..", ".."}
    };
    memcpy(positions, defaultPositions, size);
}

int main(void)
{
    char arr[5][6][2];
    setDefaultPositions(sizeof arr, arr);
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            printf("%.2s ", arr[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
() () .. .. .. .. 
/\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ 
.. .. .. .. .. .. 
/\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ 
.. .. .. .. .. ..
```

Bear in mind that the array elements are not strings – they have no terminator.

Comment: Thank you, now i understand it, works perfect

Answer (score 0):

Arrays cannot be modified by an assignment because in C all values of arrays decay to a pointer to array's first element. Therefore, it not possible to execute:

```
array = value-of-array
```

Therefore arrays can only by assignment "by element" or with "memcpy()".

A quite reliable and type-safe method is passing a pointer to a whole array:

```
#include <string.h>

void setDefaultPositions(char (*positions)[5][6][2]) {
    char defaultPositions[5][6][2] = {
        {"()", "()", "..", "..", "..", ".."},
        {"/\\", "/\\", "/\\", "/\\", "/\\", "/\\"},
        {"..", "..", "..", "..", "..", ".."},
        {"/\\", "/\\", "/\\", "/\\", "/\\", "/\\"},
        {"..", "..", "..", "..", "..", ".."}
    };
    memcpy(positions, &defaultPositions, sizeof *positions);
}

int main(void) {
    char arr[5][6][2];
    setDefaultPositions(&arr);
}
```

Passing an array of a different dimensions (i.e. `char[3][6][2]`) will raise a warning from a compiler.

Comment: Did you test this? `sizeof *positions` is `12`.

Comment: @WeatherVane, No. It's 60, not 12. The code is correct. See https://godbolt.org/z/1YhsvdMo7

Comment: Since your edit it outputs the right values.

Comment: @WeatherVane, what warning? Have you seen the godbolt I've sent you?

Comment: Uh I thought I had copied your code.

Comment: `void setDefaultPositions(char positions [5][6][2])` ... `memcpy(positions, defaultPositions, sizeof defaultPostitions);` would make the API a bit less cumbersome.

Comment: @Lundin, but it silently accept a smaller array like `int[3][6][2]`. I know that modern compilers raise a warning in such a case but technically it is an overzealous notification until one declares parameter as `char positions [static 5][6][2]`.

Comment: Since `static` actually works on several compiler nowadays, then maintaining type safety in multi-dimensional array decay is a good use for that feature IMO.